# How to find license key with CMD or powershell without upgrading powershell to version 3.0

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell, license

I have an issue cause I am trying to deploy a script which lists the major data of PCs, but unfortunately I cannot get license key of anything. All the computers in the company (except IT) use Windows 7 Pro and have powershell v 2.0. I need to get license key, but do not have any ideas. I tried going cmd and then "wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey" but this does not work.
Suggestions?

Comment: but `wmic` isn't a PowerShell feature, it is an [external Windows command](https://www.computerhope.com/wmic.htm).  You can run it from a `cmd.exe` prompt.... What do you actually see when you run that command?

Comment: As I wrote, i used wmic on cmd, not on powershell. Cmd then says invalid node and pc name.

Comment: Please be more descriptive than "does not work".   The command you issued only works on Windows 8.0+.  It also does not work if you are using a retail or volume license key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One from the past.

[How to get the Windows product key without using third party software](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-get-the-windows-product-key-without-using-third-party-software)

> If you lost, cannot retrieve or forgot where you had stored the
>   product key of your Windows 8.1, Windows 8 or Windows 7 OS, do not
>   despair. I would like to show you a simple solution to extract your
>   product key from the OS installed on your PC without using any third
>   party software.

```
function Get-WindowsKey 
{
    ## function to retrieve the Windows Product Key from any PC
    ## by Jakob Bindslet (jakob@bindslet.dk)
    param ($targets = ".")
    $hklm = 2147483650
    $regPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    $regValue = "DigitalProductId"
    Foreach ($target in $targets) {
        $productKey = $null
        $win32os = $null
        $wmi = [WMIClass]"\\$target\root\default:stdRegProv"
        $data = $wmi.GetBinaryValue($hklm,$regPath,$regValue)
        $binArray = ($data.uValue)[52..66]
        $charsArray = "B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","M","P","Q","R","T","V","W","X","Y","2","3","4","6","7","8","9"
        ## decrypt base24 encoded binary data
        For ($i = 24; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
            $k = 0
            For ($j = 14; $j -ge 0; $j--) {
                $k = $k * 256 -bxor $binArray[$j]
                $binArray[$j] = [math]::truncate($k / 24)
                $k = $k % 24
            }
            $productKey = $charsArray[$k] + $productKey
            If (($i % 5 -eq 0) -and ($i -ne 0)) {
                $productKey = "-" + $productKey
            }
        }
        $win32os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $target
        $obj = New-Object Object
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Computer -value $target
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty Caption -value $win32os.Caption
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty CSDVersion -value $win32os.CSDVersion
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty OSArch -value $win32os.OSArchitecture
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty BuildNumber -value $win32os.BuildNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty RegisteredTo -value $win32os.RegisteredUser
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductID -value $win32os.SerialNumber
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty ProductKey -value $productkey
        $obj
    }
}
```